# Should the tag "Range-variable" exist for C# programmers?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm starting to explore the topic of [Range Variables](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/03/28/range-variables-is-it-just-me-that-thinks-they-re-different.aspx) and want to know if I should create the tag, and tag the questions appropriately.

Comment: Too localized? Voter is on crack.

Comment: You'd have to look *really* hard to tag questions appropriately with this.  If the problem is specifically dealing with those range variables, then *maybe*, but generally, I don't think this is a good idea as most questions aren't going to be around range variables, but will involve them in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree.  C# range variables are, near as I can tell, simply a part of the language.  I don't believe there should be a unique tag for keywords or other basic elements of a particular language.

I know that there are some tags for specific language keywords already, such as [volatile], which have been allowed to survive.  If there were a rule to not have tags for language features, perhaps there would be some exceptions in special cases.

Then again, I don't think so.  The C++ keyword `volatile` is complex, misunderstood and the subject of frequent debate, but tagging questions with [volatile] doesn't really help anybody searching for information about `volatile`, nor does it help front-page contributors to know which questions to read any more than a thoughtful subject would.

Comment: along the lines of `volatile` how about [pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:241536+[pointers]) [templates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:241536+[templates]) or [class](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:241536+[class])

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter:  I think those fall in the same category as `volatile`.